# How create a group variable from the two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot, lateral-join

I have the following table

[image]

How can I achieve the following table result:

[image]

group1 and group2 should be united in one column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cross apply` to unpivot your dataset:

```
select g.twogroups, t.year, t.quantity
from mytable t
cross apply (values (t.group1), (t.group2)) as g(twogroups)
```

Comment: Thank you, it is working, but is there any faster approach to do it? In reality, I got 10 calculated columns with 500k rows and it takes a lot of time when cross apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `union` as follows:

```
select group1 as twogroup, quantity, year from t
union
select group1, quantity, year from t
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to unpivot the data.  I would recommend `apply`:

```
select v.twogroups, t.quantity, t.year
from t cross apply
     (values (t.group1), (t.group2)
     ) v(twogroups);
```

Comment: Thank you, it is working, but is there any faster approach to do it? In reality, I got 10 calculated columns with 500k rows and it takes a lot of time when cross apply.

Comment: @ErkoTru . . . This *is* the fastest approach.  The issue is -- in all likelihood -- the time taken to handle 5 million rows of data.  Saving them in a table, for instance, is usually faster than returning them to a GUI.